# In a group endomorphism between two sets, must the binary operation of the two sets be the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, group-homomorphism

Let $(G,\ast)$ and $(G,\cdot)$ be any two groups, where $\ast$ and $\cdot$ are distinct binary operations. Suppose $\phi:G\to G$ satisfies
$$
\phi(x)\cdot \phi(y)=\phi(x\ast y)
$$
for all $x,y\in G$. Is $\phi$ a group endomorphism? In other words, for a homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$ to be an endomorphism, do we simply require that the set $G$ equals $H$, or do we also require that the binary operations are equal as functions?

Comment: What does "the same" mean here?  Do you mean that the multiplication tables must match exactly?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu: Yes, I mean that the multiplication tables must match exactly, i.e. the functions $\ast$ and $\cdot$ are equal. I've edited my post to clarify this.

Comment: Then of course the answer is No.  Consider the cyclic group of order $6$, generated by an element $a$ or order $2$ and an element $b$ of order $3$.  We could also have the same set but now $a$ has order $3$ and $b$ has order $2$.  The map which interchanges $a,b$ is an isomorphism, but the group laws aren't "the same".

Comment: Or, more simply, take the group of order $2$ and switch the role of the identity and the generator.

Comment: But...normally one only speaks of group laws "up to isomorphism".  the names you assign to the various group elements doesn't mean much.

Comment: I think what the OP means is this. Consider a homomorphism $j:G\to H$, where the set of elements for $G$ and the set of elements for $H$ have the same cardinality. Is it the case that whichever bijection $f:H\to G$ we use, we regard $g\mapsto f(j(g))$ as an endomorphism? Not according to the definition of a group endomorphism as linked to in my answer

Comment: @lulu: Can I give an example to ensure that I am understanding you? Let $G=\{a,b\}$ and consider the groups $(G,\ast)$ and $(G,\cdot)$, where $\ast$ and $\cdot$ are defined as follows:
$$
a\ast a=a \quad b\cdot b=b\\
a\ast b=b \quad b\cdot a = a\\
b\ast a=b \quad a\cdot b=a\\
b\ast b=a \quad a\cdot a=b
$$
I think what you are saying is that the function $\phi:G\to G$ which maps $a$ to $b$ and $b$ to $a$ is an endomorphism, as the domain of $\phi$ equals the codomain, and the group operation is preserved.

Comment: The issue here is, I think, what are the objects in the category you have in mind?  I'm only used to considering groups up to isomorphism.   I agree it is different if you say that changing the names produces a new object in your category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An endomorphism of $(G,*)$ is, by definition, a homomorphism from $(G,*)$ to $(G,*)$. Thus, in your formulation, we require $* = \cdot$ (as functions $G\times G \to G$).

Answer (score 2):

According to https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Endomorphism_of_a_group,

the criterion is $\sigma(gh)=\sigma(g)\sigma(h)$. Notice they don't refer to two different binary operations.